# Как решить проблему с cors в Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Пишу авторизацию через Steam на введите сюда описание изображениябеке. На фронте пишу с Nuxt. Прокси настроила. В next.config.js в modules добавила плагин nuxtjs/proxy. Отправлять запросы на бек с фронта могу, но во время редиректа на страницу для авторизации в Steam получаю cors ошибку. Без nuxt такой ошибки нет.

Для теста склонировала репозиторий passport-steam и на фронте написала ссылку на адрес бека, который использую для проекта с Nuxt. Ошибки не было. Редирект на страницу для авторизации в Steam сработал.

Пробовала и с

```
this.$axios.get('/api/auth/steam')
```

и с обычным запросом к axios

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/steam')
```

Думаю, проблема связана с Nuxt, тк без него все работает нормально.

[image]

Comment: Nuxt никак не должен быть связан с этим. Вы уверены, что правильно настроен CORS в API?

Comment: На бекенде точно все нормально, тк без Nuxt все работает(с Next работает все). Запрос на бек отправляется и с Nuxt, но с Nuxt ошибка cors во время редиректа.

Comment: Проверяйте заголовки, которые получаете с сервера. Сервер не может определить домен как разешенный, поэтому и разворачивает. Вторая возможная проблема: ошибка в скрипте на сервере (возможно, какой-то параметр неверный), тогда скрипт просто не прописывает заголовки, т.к прерывается раньше.

Comment: Т.е в любом случае проблема связана с сервером. На клиенте всё равно, что Nuxt, что Next, да хоть jQuery — клиент просто отправляет запрос и получает ответ.

Comment: Если вы запускаете это локально, то из за неправильной настройки CORS запросы с разных портов буду блокироваться. Проверьте это